# How can I get rid of each element wrapped by the array key separately while converting array of object to xml?

Tags: javascript, json, xml

While converting an array of object into xml, each element inside the array gets wrapped with the array key in the xml. How can I make all element wrapped by the array key for once?

the problem is for each element in the array gets wrapped by the array key separately while converting the xml.

my json is like:

```
  {a: 
      [
       {first: 1}, 
       {second:2}
      ] 
  }
```

this gets converted to

```
    <a>
      <first> </first>
    </a>
    <a>
      <second> </second>
    </a>
```

but what I want is

```
    <a>
       <first> </first>
       <second> </second>
    </a>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the script used to obtain that output.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
function OBJtoXML(obj) {
  var xml = '';
  for (var prop in obj) {
    xml += obj[prop] instanceof Array ? '' : "<" + prop + ">";
    if (obj[prop] instanceof Array) {
      xml += "<" + prop + ">";
      for (var array in obj[prop]) {
        xml += OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop][array]));
      }
      xml += "</" + prop + ">";
    } else if (typeof obj[prop] == "object") {
      xml += OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop]));
    } else {
      xml += obj[prop];
    }
    xml += obj[prop] instanceof Array ? '' : "</" + prop + ">";
  }
  var xml = xml.replace(/<\/?[0-9]{1,}>/g, '');
  return xml
}
```